# Convert array of integers into dictionary of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a (large) integer array like

```
materials = [0, 0, 47, 0, 2, 2, 47]  # ...
```

with few unique entries and I'd like to convert it into a dictionary of indices, i.e.,

```
d = {
    0: [0, 1, 3],
    2: [4, 5],
    47: [2, 6],
    }
```

What's the most efficient way of doing so? (NumPy welcome.)

Comment: I don't think numpy has much in the way of creating dictionaries, pandas might but I think you just mean to say "optimized libraries welcome" yes?

Comment: The best one here is Tadhg's, followed by Roman's which is 1.5 times slower but it is pretty good too (no difference virtually). Jean's is 40 times slower than Tadhg's answer. :)

Comment: @frederick99 I think the difference between Jean's and mine would rely heavily on the length of the list as the orders of runtimes is quite different.  I perticularly notice Jean's solution works quite fast when there are only one or two unique elements.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I ran it on a list with a million elements :| Isn't that good enough?

Comment: I repeat "the difference will depend on the length" if you try with a small list the difference isn't as drastic.  Size isn't all that matters ;)

Comment: Well, the OP did hint that the list is large. :P

Comment: my answer uses a dict comp, but it's slow because of index linear lookup. One-liners are not always the most efficient choice.

Comment: I made some timings. Needless to say that I win ;-) I've posted the benchmarking code. Feel free to play with it.

Comment: FYI I've added a version `pp3` that performs well when the number of elements is much larger than the number of unique elements (like 1,000,000 vs. 100). This `perfplot` module where does it come from? Looks neat.

Comment: @PaulPanzer A little tool of mine. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/perfplot

Comment: Nice! Will check it out -- tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one-liner, this time with `numpy.where`:

```
out = {v: np.where(v == a)[0] for v in numpy.unique(a)}
```

(For some applications, the Boolean array may be enough:

```
out = {v: v == a for v in numpy.unique(a)}
```

)

Note that `numpy.unique` is faster than `set()` for large arrays, and by a large margin if there are only a few unique entries.

Anyhow, for most array sizes, the above is the fastest method yet:

10 different integers:
[image]

100 different integers:
[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import perfplot


def pp(a):
    index = np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort')
    as_ = a[index]
    jumps = np.r_[0, 1 + np.where(np.diff(as_) != 0)[0]]
    pp_out = {k: v for k, v in zip(as_[jumps], np.split(index, jumps[1:]))}
    return pp_out


def pp2(a):
    index = np.argsort(a)
    as_ = a[index]
    jumps = np.r_[0, 1 + np.where(np.diff(as_) != 0)[0]]
    pp_out = {k: np.sort(v)
              for k, v in zip(as_[jumps], np.split(index, jumps[1:]))}
    return pp_out


def Denziloe_JFFabre(a):
    df_out = {v: [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == v] for v in np.unique(a)}
    return df_out


def FCouzo(a):
    fc_out = defaultdict(list)
    for i, elem in enumerate(a):
        fc_out[elem].append(i)
    return fc_out


def KKSingh(a):
    kks_out = defaultdict(list)
    list(map(lambda x: kks_out[x[0]].append(x[1]), zip(a, range(len(a)))))
    return kks_out


def TMcDonaldJensen(a):
    mdj_out = defaultdict(list)
    for i, elem in enumerate(a):
        mdj_out[elem].append(i)
    return mdj_out


def RomanPerekhrest(a):
    rp_out = {}
    for k, m in enumerate(a):
        rp_out.setdefault(m, []).append(k)
    return rp_out


def SchloemerHist(a):
    np.histogram(a, bins=np.arange(min(a), max(a)+2))
    return


def SchloemerWhere(a):
    out = {v: np.where(v == a)[0] for v in np.unique(a)}
    return out


def SchloemerBooleanOnly(a):
    out = {v: v == a for v in np.unique(a)}
    return out


perfplot.show(
        setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
        kernels=[
            pp, pp2, Denziloe_JFFabre, FCouzo, KKSingh,
            TMcDonaldJensen, RomanPerekhrest, SchloemerHist, SchloemerWhere,
            SchloemerBooleanOnly
            ],
        n_range=[2**k for k in range(17)],
        xlabel='len(a)',
        logx=True,
        logy=True,
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

no need for `numpy`, those are standard python structures, dict comprehension does that very well for your problem:

```
materials = [0, 0, 47, 0, 2, 2, 47]

d = {v : [i for i,x in enumerate(materials) if x==v] for v in set(materials)}

print(d)
```

result:

```
{0: [0, 1, 3], 2: [4, 5], 47: [2, 6]}
```

`[i for i,x in enumerate(materials) if x==v]` finds all the indexes of the element in the list (`index` only finds the first one)

In the first version of my answer I was iterating on the list itself, but that's a bit wasteful since it will overwrite the key several times when there are a lot of occurrences, and the inner list comprehension has `n` complexity so the overall complexity is not so good.

While I was writing this final comment, someone suggested to iterate on unique elements, which is good, so turn that input list to a `set`!

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution using [***enumerate()***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) and [***dict.setdefault()***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.setdefault) functions:

```
materials = [0, 0, 47, 0, 2, 2, 47]
d = {}
for k,m in enumerate(materials):
    d.setdefault(m, []).append(k)

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{0: [0, 1, 3], 2: [4, 5], 47: [2, 6]}
```

Answer (score 3):

you may find [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to be of use here, when an element is found for first time it will create a new list for you.

```
from collections import defaultdict

indices = defaultdict(list)

for i, elem in enumerate(materials):
    indices[elem].append(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000000)
index = np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort')
as_  = a[index]
jumps = np.r_[0, 1 + np.where(np.diff(as_) != 0)[0]]
result = {k: v for k, v in zip(as_[jumps], np.split(index, jumps[1:]))}
```

### Benchmarks

`numpy` wins for not too large `n`; since it uses an O(n log n) sort algorithm, the margins are slim (pp2 is a variant that replaces the slow but stable mergesort with quicksort at the cost of having to sort the individual index lists afterwards, pp3 replaces the full sort with `argpartition` this gains some speed if the number of unique elements is small compared to the number of elements.):

10 different integer values in the original array:
[image]

100 different integer values in the original array:
[image]

Benchmark code for reference:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import perfplot


def pp(a):
    index = np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort')
    as_ = a[index]
    jumps = np.r_[0, 1 + np.where(np.diff(as_) != 0)[0]]
    pp_out = {k: v for k, v in zip(as_[jumps], np.split(index, jumps[1:]))}
    return pp_out


def pp2(a):
    index = np.argsort(a)
    as_ = a[index]
    jumps = np.r_[0, 1 + np.where(np.diff(as_) != 0)[0]]
    pp_out = {k: np.sort(v)
              for k, v in zip(as_[jumps], np.split(index, jumps[1:]))}
    return pp_out


def Denziloe_JFFabre(a):
    df_out = {v: [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == v] for v in set(a)}
    return df_out


def FCouzo(a):
    fc_out = defaultdict(list)
    for i, elem in enumerate(a):
        fc_out[elem].append(i)
    return fc_out


def KKSingh(a):
    kks_out = defaultdict(list)
    list(map(lambda x: kks_out[x[0]].append(x[1]), zip(a, range(len(a)))))
    return kks_out


def TMcDonaldJensen(a):
    mdj_out = defaultdict(list)
    for i, elem in enumerate(a):
        mdj_out[elem].append(i)
    return mdj_out


def RomanPerekhrest(a):
    rp_out = {}
    for k, m in enumerate(a):
        rp_out.setdefault(m, []).append(k)
    return rp_out


def SchloemerHist(a):
    np.histogram(a, bins=np.arange(min(a), max(a)+2))
    return


def SchloemerWhere(a):
    out = {v: np.where(v == a)[0] for v in set(a)}
    return out


perfplot.show(
        setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(0, 10, n),
        kernels=[
            pp, pp2, Denziloe_JFFabre, FCouzo, KKSingh,
            TMcDonaldJensen, RomanPerekhrest, SchloemerHist, SchloemerWhere
            ],
        n_range=[2**k for k in range(19)],
        xlabel='len(a)',
        logx=True,
        logy=True,
        )
```

Comment: the comprehension `{k: v for k, v in <iter>}` can be replaced by `dict(<iter>)` and using Cpython it'd run faster since the iteration would be handled purely in C instead of in python.

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensions can do this nicely:

```
d = {key:[i for i, v in enumerate(materials) if v == key] for key in set(materials)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `defaultdict`, it is more efficient (`O(n)` time, compared to Jean's answer, which is `O(n^2)`):

```
from collections import defaultdict
materials = [0, 0, 47, 0, 2, 2, 47]
d = defaultdict(list)
for i, elem in enumerate(materials):
    d[elem].append(i)
```

`d` is now equal to:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [0, 1, 3], 2: [4, 5], 47: [2, 6]})
```

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of it, here's a solution using [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
np.histogram(a, bins=np.arange(min(a), max(a)+2))
```

I thought it might perform well, but Paul's solution is still better:

[image]